# Is it possible to set a timer task in vim7

Tags: vimscript

As we know, we can set a highlight color while searching a keyword.

I'm wondering if I can set a timer task to clear the highlight color after a few seconds.

For now, I have to type `:noh<CR>` to clear the highlight color. If setting a timer task is possible, I'd like to set a timer task as below:

1. searching a keyword
2. 5 seconds later, `:noh<CR>` is executed automatically

Comment: Do you have `+timers` in `:version`? It was added in Vim 7.4.1578, so you may have it even on Vim 7.

Comment: As usual, you can also create a mapping to the `:nohlsearch` command to make this faster, but still manual

Comment: @MartinTournoij Yes I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> :noh is executed automatically

Well, that's kind of prohibited.

> :h function-search-undo
>
> The last used search pattern and the redo command "." will not be changed by the function.  This also implies that the effect of |:nohlsearch| is undone when the function returns.

Note that internally all autocommands are functions, so `:noh` inside an autocommand won't have any effect either.

Therefore, you are more or less confined to `feedkeys()` like that

```
augroup autonoh | au!
    autocmd CursorHold * if v:hlsearch | call feedkeys(":noh\<CR>", 'n') | endif
augroup end
```

(Don't try to make use of `timer_start()` even if you have it in Vim7, as for this case you'll certainly also need `SafeState`, but it's available in Vim 8.1+ only).

Still, that does not feel good to me, so I believe that a mapping (`nnoremap <C-L> :noh<CR><C-L>`, or whatever) should be preferred.